# Facing challenge in testing lambda locally inside docker

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, aws-cli, aws-sam-cli, sam

I am working inside Docker. I have started the docker-container using below command (from base image of Linux Ubuntu) and have installed all necessary softwares inside the Container like "sudo", "JDK", "maven", "vim", "aws-cli", "sam-cli", etc.

`docker container run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -it ubuawsimg`

I am perfectly able to run and execute "sam build" && "sam deploy" commands inside my docker-container, but when I try to execute the command like `sam local invoke HelloWorldFunction/ --event events/testEventWithOneParameter.json` I am getting below error :-

```
root@028cce033ce7:/adityaLearningLambda# sam local invoke HelloWorldFunction --event events/testEventWithOneParameter.json
Invoking helloworld.App::hello (java8)
Skip pulling image and use local one: public.ecr.aws/sam/emulation-java8:rapid-1.37.0-x86_64.

Mounting /adityaLearningLambda/.aws-sam/build/HelloWorldFunction as /var/task:ro,delegated inside runtime container
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 261, in _raise_for_status
  File "requests/models.py", line 943, in raise_for_status
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.35/containers/d1652eec654969d7c935ca20f1ad265b0c5182cc500a3910abe9a1fa9cc356b6/start

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "samcli/__main__.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
  File "click/core.py", line 782, in main
  File "click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
  File "click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
  File "click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
  File "click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
  File "click/decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
  File "click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
  File "samcli/lib/telemetry/metric.py", line 166, in wrapped
  File "samcli/lib/telemetry/metric.py", line 124, in wrapped
  File "samcli/lib/utils/version_checker.py", line 41, in wrapped
  File "samcli/cli/main.py", line 87, in wrapper
  File "samcli/commands/local/invoke/cli.py", line 106, in cli
  File "samcli/commands/local/invoke/cli.py", line 183, in do_cli
  File "samcli/commands/local/lib/local_lambda.py", line 144, in invoke
  File "samcli/lib/telemetry/metric.py", line 230, in wrapped_func
  File "samcli/local/lambdafn/runtime.py", line 179, in invoke
  File "samcli/local/lambdafn/runtime.py", line 133, in run
  File "samcli/local/docker/manager.py", line 117, in run
  File "samcli/local/docker/container.py", line 273, in start
  File "docker/models/containers.py", line 400, in start
  File "docker/utils/decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
  File "docker/api/container.py", line 1095, in start
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 263, in _raise_for_status
  File "docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception
docker.errors.APIError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("b'Mounts denied: \nThe path /adityaLearningLambda/.aws-sam/build/HelloWorldFunction is not shared from the host and is not known to Docker.\nYou can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> Resources -> File Sharing.\nSee https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac for more info.'")
[27] Failed to execute script __main__
```

Please note that, I don't have any directory named `adityaLearningLambda` at my local host. Here is the directory structure looks like inside my docker container :-

```
root@028cce033ce7:/# 
root@028cce033ce7:/# cd adityaLearningLambda/
root@028cce033ce7:/adityaLearningLambda# pwd
/adityaLearningLambda
root@028cce033ce7:/adityaLearningLambda# ls -la
total 40
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root    4096 Jan 16 16:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    4096 Jan 19 18:04 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Jan 18 06:48 .aws-sam
drwxr-xr-x 4  504 dialout 4096 Jan 16 16:07 HelloWorldFunction
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    8298 Jan 12 15:31 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Jan 17 09:29 events
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     296 Jan 14 07:15 samconfig.toml
-rw-r--r-- 1  504 dialout  662 Jan 16 11:16 template.yaml
root@028cce033ce7:/adityaLearningLambda# cd .aws-sam/
root@028cce033ce7:/adityaLearningLambda/.aws-sam# ls
build  build.toml
root@028cce033ce7:/adityaLearningLambda/.aws-sam# cd build
root@028cce033ce7:/adityaLearningLambda/.aws-sam/build# ls -la
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jan 18 06:48 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jan 18 06:48 ..
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jan 18 06:48 HelloWorldFunction
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  455 Jan 18 06:48 template.yaml
root@028cce033ce7:/adityaLearningLambda/.aws-sam/build# cd HelloWorldFunction/
root@028cce033ce7:/adityaLearningLambda/.aws-sam/build/HelloWorldFunction# ls
helloworld  lib
root@028cce033ce7:/adityaLearningLambda/.aws-sam/build/HelloWorldFunction# cd helloworld/
root@028cce033ce7:/adityaLearningLambda/.aws-sam/build/HelloWorldFunction/helloworld# ls
App.class  AppSimple.class
root@028cce033ce7:/adityaLearningLambda/.aws-sam/build/HelloWorldFunction/helloworld# pwd
/adityaLearningLambda/.aws-sam/build/HelloWorldFunction/helloworld
root@028cce033ce7:/adityaLearningLambda/.aws-sam/build/HelloWorldFunction/helloworld#
```

How do I solve this problem ? Any responses shall be highly appreciated.

--
Best
aditya

Comment: The docker container has its own virtual filesystem, it doesn't see your local files automatically (try to run the *ls* command in the container). You may *mount* part of the filesystem needed to share needed files

Comment: @gusto2 Thanks for responding. But I don't have any files present at my local filesystem at my host. I have my entire Lambda function codebase at my container only.